# How do I add in decimals to my current working code without butchering it?

Tags: c++, floating-point

I have been cracking at this code all day and when I think I am making ground I seem to take one step forward and two steps back.

I am currently using Visual Studios 2013 update 4 and I was wondering if someone could help me incorporate being able to use decimals for the output calculations in the working code I have completed so far.

I have tried using the double variable, but all that does is throw up 1120 errors or do nothing at all.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
// Chapter 7 Problem #3
// Rainfall Statistics
// 4-7-15

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

// Functions prototypes
void getRain(string[], int[], int);
int getTotal(int[], int);
int getAve(int[], int);
int largestElement(int[], int);
int smallestElement(int[], int);

int main()
{
    // Costant for the number of Month entries
    const int Rain_Per_Month = 12;

    //Array of Months
    string names[Rain_Per_Month] = { "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "Decemeber" };

    // Array of inches of each month
    int inches[Rain_Per_Month];

    //Total inches of rainfall
    int totalRainFall;

    // Ave Rain Fall
    int aveRainFall;

    // Subscript of the month that had the most rain
    int highRainFall;

    // Subscript of the month that had the least rain
    int lowRainFall;

    // Get the amount of rainfall in inches of each Month.
    getRain(names, inches, Rain_Per_Month);

    // Get total rainfall and Ave rainfall and high rainfall and low rainfall in inches.
    totalRainFall = getTotal(inches, Rain_Per_Month);
    aveRainFall = getAve(inches, Rain_Per_Month);
    highRainFall = largestElement(inches, Rain_Per_Month);
    lowRainFall = smallestElement(inches, Rain_Per_Month);

    // Display the Rainfall report header.
    cout << endl << endl;
    cout << "                         12 Month Rain Report \n\n";
    cout << "______________________________________________________________\n";

    // Display the and rain in inches of each month.

    for (int Rain_Per_Month = 0.00; Rain_Per_Month < Rain_Per_Month; Rain_Per_Month++)
    {
        cout << setw(6) << names[Rain_Per_Month]
            << setw(21) << inches[Rain_Per_Month]
            << endl;
    }

    // Display the total rainfall, highest rainfall, and lowest rainfall.
    cout << "\nThe total rainfall for the year was:" << setw(15) << totalRainFall << " inches" << endl;
    cout << "The average rainfall for the year is " << aveRainFall << endl;
    cout << "The largest amount of rainfall was " << inches[highRainFall] << " inches in " << names[highRainFall] << endl;
    cout << "The smallest amount of rainfall was " << inches[lowRainFall] << " inches in " << names[lowRainFall] << endl;
    cout << "\n" << endl;

    return 0;
}

/*********************************************************
*                         getRain                        *
* Gets the amount of rain in inches of each month from   *
* the user. The names array parameter holds the names of *
* the months, and the month array parameter will hold    *
* the amount of rainfall in iches of each corresponding  *
* month.                                                 *
**********************************************************/
void getRain(string names[], int inches[], int size)
{
    for (int month = 0.00; month < size; month++)
    {
        //Get the amount of Rainfall for each month.
        cout << "How many inches of rain fall for the month of " << names[month] << ": ";
        cin >> inches[month];

        // Validate the input.
        while (inches[month] < 0.00)
        {
            cout << "Inches of rain must be 0 or more. Please re-enter: ";
            cin >> inches[month];
        }
    }
}
/**********************************************************
*                           getTotal                      *
* Calculates and returns the total of the values stored in*
* the array passed to the function.                       *
***********************************************************/
int getTotal(int array[], int size)
{
    int total = 0.00;

    for (int pos = 0.00; pos < size; pos++)
        total += array[pos];

    return total;
}
/***********************************************************
*                           getAve                         *
* Calculates the total of the values stored in             *
* the array passed to the function and then averages them. *                       *
************************************************************/
int getAve(int array[], int size)
{
    int Total = 0.00;
    double Ave;

    for (int pos = 0.00; pos < size; pos++)
        Total += array[pos];
    Ave = Total / size;

    return Ave;
}
/**********************************************************
*                             largestElement              *
* Finds and returns the subscript of the array position   *
* holding the largest value in the array passed to the    *
* function.                                               *
***********************************************************/
int largestElement(int array[], int size)
{
    int indexOfLargest = 0.00;

    for (int pos = 1; pos < size; pos++)
    {
        if (array[pos] > array[indexOfLargest])
            indexOfLargest = pos;
    }
    return indexOfLargest;
}

/**********************************************************
*                      smallestElement                    *
* Finds and returns the subscript of the array position   *
* holding the smallest value in the array passed to the   *
* function.                                               *
***********************************************************/
int smallestElement(int array[], int size)
{
    int indexOfSmallest = 0.00;

    for (int pos = 1; pos < size; pos++)
    {
        if (array[pos] < array[indexOfSmallest])
            indexOfSmallest = pos;
    }
    return indexOfSmallest;
}
```

Comment: Please trim the amount of code. You don't need all of that to ask the simple question you have.

Comment: The `double` type is the default floating point type. Please make a teeny tiny little program that does such a calculation. If it works, then your set to go, and if not, and you're unable to fix it, post that code.

Comment: can you not use float?

Comment: _"butchering it"_ and _"1120 errors"_ aren't particularly helpful (for you and the reader).  Consider being more descriptive.  This will help us help you.  Good luck!

Comment: I found out what my issue was. If you look at the top of the program where I have the prototype functions. I forgot to change the variables within those to double and the system was throwing 1120 errors when I changed the integers within the actual functions at the bottom. I also forgot to put in the "cout.precision(4);" with the functions.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be confusing the concept of 'type' with the concept of 'variable'. Each variable will contain a specific type of data, and you have to declare that yourself as you figure out what you will do with it.

For example: there are exactly 12 months, so you should declare anything dealing with the month number as an integer.

Another example: the amount of rainfall can be fractions of an inch, so anything dealing with rainfall amounts, totals, averages, maximums, or minimums should be declared as a floating-point type, such as float or double.

Finally, as a general hint, go reread and fix your variable names. You have this:

> ```
> // Costant for the number of Month entries
> const int Rain_Per_Month = 12;
> ```

but you obviously mean Months_Per_Year. You'll find that if you fix the names to accurately describe what they mean, you'll probably understand your code better.

Comment: Oops, I forgot to change that one. That is a great catch on the editing portion of my code thanks!

Comment: Originally I did have my variables (int, double) to match the months, averages, etc. . . What I was having problems with that I didn't realize until I messed with them a little is that the prototype functions I had at the top of my program needed to have the integers inside them to be changed to double.  when I was getting the 1120 errors. Since they didn't highlight them I completely forgot they were even there as I changed the functions at the bottom.